# Resteasy always get application/json content type on request

Tags: java, angularjs, jboss, resteasy

I have a web application that use Angularjs on frontend och Resteasy + Jackson on the back end. I'm sending a file from Angular component to a REST method, receiving method looks like this :

```
@POST
@Path("/upload/attachment/for/{eventId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input,
                           final @PathParam("eventId") Long eventId,
                           @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
    ...my awesome stuff...

    return Response.ok().build();

}
```

And request has following headers when sent :

```
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  347085
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------12164806981346771846716776342
Cookie  JSESSIONID=aoBd1hgzR3GM8bSG5P-9g-vQ; csrftoken=ziQ7kN7TlMehR2aURDrmaMLYAroMsSpu
Host    localhost:9000
Referer http://localhost:9000/local/myapp/index.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
```

The problem is that THIS request ALWAYS has `application/json` as a Content-Type instead for `multipart/form-data` as it says in the headers. And I get :

```
20:12:00,490 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Failed executing POST /events/upload/attachment/for/null: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Cannot consume content type
```

Already in `HttpServletDispatcher` the content is wrong.

I can't get if this is JBOSS that set Content-Type to wrong value or some thing else.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was that I have an extra layer between angular and server which runs on Node.js and it just tunel requests to the server. I had to add following :

```
var r = null;
r = request.put({uri: url, json: inReq.body, headers: inReq.headers, form: inReq.form});
inReq.pipe(r).pipe(inRes);
```

This set all the headers from outgoing request and tunnel the request
Now I have right `content-type`